# Creating an instance of CALayer

Tags: c++, objective-c, core-animation

I'm coding in C++ using CoreAnimation.

In Objective-C the CALayer instance is being created with [CALayer layer] message call.

How do I create a CALayer instance in C++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Objective-C++ (give your files the .mm extension). Then it's also just `[CALayer layer]`. Otherwise, you have to use the C-based Objective C runtime, which is very cumbersome.

Comment: Does it mean tha CoreAnimation can't be used in pure C++/C based projects ?

Comment: Without the Objective C runtime, no. What do you intend to do?